# Cannot import assets via main.js file in Vite.js

Tags: vite, homestead

I run Laravel Homestead on Windows 10.

I have several Laravel sites on this box using Vite.js. I am now trying to run a simple Vite project without Laravel, but I'm having some internal Vite.js problem where assets cannot be imported from main.js.

As with all sites I run on this box (up until now only Laravel sites) I use a virtual host.

On the windows drivers/etc/hosts file:

```
192.168.10.10 mysite.local
```

On the homestead.yaml file I map mysite.local to the location of the site:

```
- map: mysite.local
  to: /home/vagrant/code/mysite
```

This works perfectly with Laravel+Vite, but not with Vite alone.

On Firefox I see the following error messages in the console:

```
Script from “http://mysite.local/public/vite.svg” was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“image/svg+xml”).

Loading module from “http://mysite.local/style.css” was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“text/css”).

Script from “http://mysite.local/javascript.svg” was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“image/svg+xml”).
```

In the Network tab of the developer tools these assets are blocked and there is an error message:

```
NS_ERROR_CORRUPTED_CONTENT
```

On Chrome I see the following error messages on the console:

```
Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "image/svg+xml". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "image/svg+xml". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/css". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
```

In the Network tab of the developer tools these assets are show as if they were imported without error (200 status code).

my vite.config.js :

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import dns from 'dns'
dns.setDefaultResultOrder('verbatim');

export default defineConfig({
    server: {
        hmr: {
            host: 'http://mydomain.local',
        },
        watch: {
            usePolling: true
        }
    },
});
```

I have tried endlessly to change the config file, trying many options such as 'base', 'publicDir', 'origin' etc.. nothing works.

I should not that the assets are available when i paste their urls in the browser.

HMR IS working btw.

Any idea how I can get these assets to load properly?